# Can I enter Romania with a single entry Cyprus visa?

Tags: visas, romania, cyprus

Assuming I hold a single entry Cyprus visa, can I use it to enter Romania if the single entry is valid and unused?

Answer (score 3):

Both short-term and long-stay visas issued by Cyprus are valid in Romania for transit or visits up to ninety days, provided any entry limits have not been exhausted.

Quoting from the [Romanian Department of Foreign Affairs web site:](https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040)

> Holders of Schengen visas with two or multiple entries, national visas
>   or residence permits issued by Schengen Member States. Starting July
>   11, 2014, in keeping with the provisions of Decision No 565/2014/EU,
>   Romania acknowledges as being equivalent to its own national visas,
>   for transit and for stays up to 90 days per period of 180 days the
>   following:
>
> The two or multiple entry short-stay visa issued by a
>   Schengen member state;
>
> The limited territorial validity visa issued by
>   a Schengen member state;
>
> The short-stay visa issued by Bulgaria,
>   Cyprus or Croatia;
>
> The long-stay visa issued by a Schengen member
>   state;
>
> The long-stay visa issued by Bulgaria, Cyprus or Croatia;
>
> The residence permit issued by a Schengen member state;
>
> The residence permit issued by Bulgaria, Cyprus or Croatia
>
> The long-term resident's EC residence permit (the validity of which is of 5 years or more) issued by a member state of the European Union.
>
> **Attention**! The number
>   of entries as well as the right of stay established as per the
>   Schengen visas must not have been exhausted. The right of stay on the
>   territory of Romania shall not exceed the right of stay granted as per
>   the visas/residence permits issued by the Schengen Member States

Comment: If the answer to the question is yes, it would amount to Cyprus issuing visas solely for entry to Romania. The question specifies a single entry Cyprus visa. All of your answer refers to two or multi entry visas.

Comment: @user16259 The OP specifies a Cyprus visa, which I'd interpreted as a national visa in the above text. The wording doesn't specify a multi-entry requirement for national visas.

Comment: Not saying you're wrong, just that it is bizarre if a citizen of say, USA, wants to go to Romania (and, seemingly, not go to Cyprus) on a single entry visa and he can apply to Cyprus to accomplish this.

Comment: @user16259 Haha, so I'm confused here, does it matter if the visa is single entry or no?

Comment: @user16259 That's not the case, Cyprus is not supposed to issue visas solely for visits to Romania and it doesn't follow from the question that they do. One scenario would a visit to Romania followed by a visit to Cyprus. That's possible on a single-entry Cyprus visa because a visit to Romania doesn't count as an entry for that visa.